# rails state machine not working inside rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rake, state-machine, rake-task

I am using the state_machine gem.  I am already using the state_machine gem successfully on one of my models, but i can't get it to work on another.  In my task model, here is the state machine:

```
state_machine :state, :initial => :incomplete do
    event :task_finished do
        transition :incomplete => :needs_approval 
    end
end
```

When a new task is created, the state column is initially set to incomplete, so I know the state_machine is working somewhat.  The problem is that in a rake task I call the :task_finished event but it does not work.  Here is the rake task:

```
task :change_it => :environment do
  puts "task is working"
  @tasks = Task.already_expired
  @tasks.each do |tasko|
      tasko.task_finished
    puts "Kalabar" + tasko.inspect + "now time is:" + DateTime.now.to_s
      puts "time_frame is:" + tasko.time_frame.to_s
  end
end
```

How do I get it to work?

The task is getting completed because the put statements are putting to the sever, but the state is not changing from :incomplete to :needs_approval as it should.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say what is wrong it is not enough information. But I can suggest you to add `!` to method `task_finished` (so you will have `tasko.task_finished!`). In this way StateMachine raise an exception - and you will see what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me find a validation that was getting in the way.  Appreciate it!